# Static method with generic argument type

Tags: java, generics

I have the following Java classes that inherit from `Object` class (Generated code).

```
public class A extends Object {
  public String getName() {
    return "A"
  }
}

public class B extends Object {
  public String getName() {
    return "B"
  }
}
```

I also have a class called `Data`

```
public class Data {
  private String name;

  public setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

I want to create `static` method that accepts (`A`, `B` ...) and return `Data`. I defined the following `Mapper` class but `getName` is not defined on type `T`

```
public class DataMapper {
  public static <T extends Object> Data map(T input) {
    Data data = new Data();
    data.setName(input.getName()); // <-- Cannot resolve getName

    return data;
  }
}
```

And this is how I call `map` method

```
...
public void processA(A input) {
  Data data = DataMapper.map(input);
  // Do more with data
  ...
}

public void processB(B input) {
  Data data = DataMapper.map(input);
  // Do more with data
  ...
}
...
```

This gives me a compiled error and I'm not sure how I can achieve this (Mapping `A` and `B` to `Data`) and I hope someone in here can help.

Note that I won't be able to change the inheritance of `A` and `B` since it is generated code and using `ObjectMapper` is not an option.

Comment: All class types are subclasses, directly or indirectly, of Object.  Thus 'T extends Object' is any class type whatsoever..  The compiler cannot guess that you want to use only 2 particular types out of the infinity of possibilities.

Comment: Because `A` and `B` are unrelated classes, their `getName` methods are also unrelated, and you can't have a name which refers to both.

Comment: If I had many of these classes, and there *really* was no way to introduce an interface, I'd consider reflection.

Answer (score 2):

You could overload two `map` methods. One that takes an `A` and one that takes a `B`. And, you could do it in `Data`. Like,

```
public class Data {
    private String name;

    public Data(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static Data map(A a) {
        return new Data(a.getName());
    }

    public static Data map(B b) {
        return new Data(b.getName());
    }
}
```